# I want back to page 3 from page 6 and remove stack Page 4,5,6 ? (image example)

Tags: dart, flutter

HOW TO BACK TO PAGE 3 and remove stack Page 4,5,6

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ww5Y5.png)

Comment: Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and specifically read about creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also, what you appear to be trying to do will likely require using something like [`Navigator.popUntil()`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Navigator/popUntil.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you use Router for navigation than you should be use

`Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName('/page3'));`